# web scraping multiple pages past a login using python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to scrape two tables on separate pages after accessing the site through a login. Tried a few different ways and can't figure it out.
The last attempt showed some promise but only the first data frame was appended to the list of data frames. Something like the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
   

    def text_to_chart (url, table) :
    
    df_list = []
   
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    driver.get(login)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(password block).send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(username block).send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(submit).click()
    time.sleep(10)

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for url, table in zip(urls, tables) :
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)
        soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'html')
        new_table = soup.find_all('table',
                  attrs = {'class': table})
        results_list = pd.read_html(str(new_table[0]))
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(results_list[0]))
       
    return df


    def scrape(url, table)
        df_list = []
        df_list = df_list.append(text_to_chart(url, table))
    
    
    scrape(url_list, table_list)
```

So, What Should I do to scrape multiple pages?

Comment: I think it's gonna be a hot topic question. So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: This wouldn’t work to scrape the table from both pages. I’m trying to see where my error is, or if there’s a better way to go about this altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you must store the values in a list of dictionaries and then convert it to a dataframe.That will be good and easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you mean instead of two lists, pass a dictionary? Such as dict = {url: table, url: table, etc}? How would I then iterate through it to move through the pages and scrape my content?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I made a few changes which resulted in one function that created my list of df's. Then I began the session, logged in, and called the function, saving the output to my variable df_list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS



def text_to_chart (urls, tables) :

    df = []

    for url, table in zip(urls, tables) :
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)
        soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'html')
        new_table = soup.find_all('table',
              attrs = {'class': table})
        results_list = pd.read_html(str(new_table[0]))
        df.append(pd.DataFrame(results_list[0]))
   
    return df




driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(login)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password block).send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(username block).send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(submit).click()
time.sleep(10)

df_list = text_to_chart(url_list, table_list)
```